# Logger.log does not updating

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a beginner with Google App scripts.

I **expected** the log to look like this (get it with CTRL+Enter):

[18-12-07 12:46:58:630 CET] Ok ### 10

but the log **result** looks like this (get it with CTRL+Enter):

[18-12-07 12:46:58:630 CET] undefined
[18-12-07 12:46:58:631 CET] Ok ### 18-12-07_12-45

that's the **source**:

```
function doGet(e) {  
  if (e.parameter == undefined) {
    result = 'No Parameters';
    Logger.log( result + " ### 06" );
  }
  else {
    var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
    Logger.log( result + " ### 10" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are logging the request made to the Web App, it is better to use console.log instead of Logger.log. The console logs are preserved and can be accessed from your Stack Driver dashboard.

Comment: i addet: `function doGet(e) {  
  Logger.log( " ### 2" );
  console.log( " ### 2" ); ...` and all logs are empty.

Comment: @sl5net make sure you either deploy a new version or use the "dev" testing url.

Comment: Surprisingly, I now get two logs: `[18-12-07 05:47:25:152 PST] Ausführung wird gestartet
[18-12-07 05:47:25:210 PST] Logger.log([ ### 2, []]) [0 Sekunden]
[18-12-07 05:47:25:215 PST] console.log([ ### 2, []]) [0,003 Sekunden]
[18-12-07 05:47:25:216 PST] Logger.log([undefined, []]) [0 Sekunden]` and `[18-12-07 05:47:25:210 PST]  ### 2
[18-12-07 05:47:25:215 PST] undefined` and not of my messages inside the javascript console.

Comment: I believe that script does not run on from the form at the moment. I think that's just a few tests from me as i clicked to the run button.

Comment: no i found howto get dev urls. from the script: publish > as webapp > copy url > add parameter manuel. problem solved. no it works  `https://script.google.com/macros/s/someHeCode/exec?col1=fistname&col2=mail@mail.de&col3=hallo`